# Calling external template from a loop in meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

From the Meteor templates tutorial here: (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates)

We see that we can call a template `{{> task}}` inside the loop over `tasks`. However, when I try to get the task template in its own file - it no longer has access to the data. What is the correct way to do this?

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: This is because you need to set a `data context` for the template. The `{{#each}}` is doing this for your main container. You can do a single document with `{{#with }}`

Comment: But I am still using #each, it's just that the task template is no longer in the same file. I'll look into setting data context for the template. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer has access to the data"? does it mean that inside `task` you can not access data of the outer template?

Comment: Yes, but as I pointed out in my answer, it wasn't because it was external, but because the helpers needed weren't available. All good now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Basically, I was importing the `task.html` in the `main.js`, but not the accompanying `task.js`. So all the conditional helpers I had were not loaded and hence not working.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass value to the template which we are calling. And I assume tasks helper is implemented. Here I'm passing current value using 'this'.

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <header>
         <h1>Todo List</h1>
      </header>
      <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
          {{> task this}}
        {{/each}}
     </ul>
  </div>
</body>
<template name="task">
   <li>{{this}}</li>
</template>
```